# expansion of $\log(2 \cos(\theta/2))$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $-\pi<\theta<\pi$ how to show that 
$$\log(2 \cos (\theta/2)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cos (n\theta)}{n}$$

Fourier expansion seems to give this result but I am looking if I could get result with expansion of $\log$. Any hints?

Comment: A similar procedure as this should work: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384479/proving-a-trig-infinite-sum-using-integration/384510#384510

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that for $\vert z \vert \leq1$ and $z \neq 1$, we have
$$\log(1+z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}z^k}k$$
Hence, setting $z=e^{it}$, where $t \neq 0$, we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1} e^{ikt}}k = \log(1+e^{it}) = \log \left(1+\cos(t) + i \sin(t) \right)$$
What you want is the real part of the above identity. Hence,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1} \cos(kt)}k = \log \left(\left \vert 1+\cos(t) + i \sin(t) \right \vert\right) = \dfrac{\log \left(2+2\cos(t) \right)}2 = \log\left(\vert2\cos(t/2)\vert\right)$$
where in the last step we made use of the identity $1+\cos(t) = 2 \vert \cos(t/2) \vert^2$.

Comment: how did $2$ come in denominator on $\dfrac{\log \left(2+2\cos(t) \right)}2 $

Comment: @MonkeyD.Luffy $\log(\sqrt{r}) = \dfrac{\log(r)}2$

Comment: ok ok ... had trouble following it up.

Answer (score 2):

Let,
$$S_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cos (n\theta)}{n}\\
S_2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin (n\theta)}{n}$$

Then $$S_1 + iS_2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}[\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)]}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}e^{in\theta}}{n}$$

Now, from the Taylor expansion, $$\ln (1+x) = x -\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3} ...=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$$

$$\begin{align} \therefore S_1+iS_2 &= \ln(1+e^{i\theta})
\\&=\ln(1+\cos\theta+i\sin \theta)
\\
&=\ln(2\cos^2(\theta/2) + 2i\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2))
\\
&=\ln(2\cos(\theta/2))+\ln(\cos\theta/2+i\sin\theta/2)
\\
&=\ln(2\cos(\theta/2))+\ln(e^{i\theta /2})
\\
&=\ln(2\cos(\theta/2))+i\theta/2
\end{align}
$$

Taking the real part of both sides,
$$S_1 = \ln(2\cos(\theta /2))$$