# What is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^8(k)$ using the sine cardinal function?

Tags: trigonometry, closed-form, pi

Given the [sine cardinal function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html),
$$\rm{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin x}x$$

for $x\neq0$. We have the nice evaluations,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}(k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^2(k)=-\tfrac12+\tfrac12\pi$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^3(k)=-\tfrac12+\tfrac38\pi$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^4(k)=-\tfrac12+\tfrac13\pi$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^5(k)=-\tfrac12+\tfrac{115}{384}\pi$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^6(k)=-\tfrac12+\tfrac{11}{40}\pi$$

then the not-so-nice,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^7(k)=-\tfrac12+\quad\\ \tfrac{1}{46080}(129423\pi-201684\pi^2+144060\pi^3-54880\pi^4+11760\pi^5-1344\pi^6+64\pi^7)$$

However, I found this can be prettified as,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^7(k)=-\frac12+\frac{7\cdot29^2\,\pi}{2^5\,6!}+\frac{\pi\big(\pi-\tfrac72\big)^6}{6!}$$

---

> **Questions:**

1. Why is the closed-form for $n=7$ far more complicated than $n<7$? (And a good lesson that "patterns" may be illusory.)
2. What is $n=8$ in terms of $\pi$? (Maybe also for $n=9$?)

---

**Update:** Courtesy of Oliver Oloa's comment, for $n=8$, after some tweaking is,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^8(k)=-\frac12+\frac{151\pi}{630}-\frac{\pi\big(\pi-\tfrac82\big)^7}{7!}$$

but $n=9$ is more complicated. See second answer below.

Comment: One may obtain$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^8(k)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{733 \pi }{210}-\frac{256 \pi ^2}{45}+\frac{64 \pi ^3}{15}-\frac{16 \pi ^4}{9}+\frac{4 \pi ^5}{9}-\frac{\pi ^6}{15}+\frac{\pi ^7}{180}-\frac{\pi ^8}{5040}.$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Could you share with us the source of that result?

Comment: @OlivierOloa: That was fast. I tried to use my old Mathematica's integer relations, but it had trouble evaluating the LHS. If you can find $n=9$ and $n=11$, can you convert your comment as an answer?

Comment: Just by using De Moivre's formula to reduce the power $\sin^8 k$ in Mathematica $10$ one obtains, with the aid of *FullSimplify* command, the above closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^8(k)$. The case $n=9$ is more involved, the  different polylogarithmic terms don't easily reduced.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Can Mathematica 10 evaluate $n=9$ to 200 deciminal digits? If I have that info, I can use Integer Relations to express it in terms of $\pi$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Ok, let me see.

Comment: It seems $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^9(k)=0.212349780254081079101781245908169128781244935800157292192\\76522425925
7401277440880592052003361787516120293782868439879153836555016542378662\\
1762579417314382007423672163404202342981696024521513857955028494227352\\ \cdots$

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Ok, found it. It is a polynomial up to $\pi^9$. Give me a while to type it.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: For $n=9$, with $x =\pi$, it is $$-1/2 + (-6498981 x + 42062688 x^2 - 59068800  x^3 + 41311872  x^4 - 16853760  x^5 + 4225536  x^6 - 645120  x^7 + 55296  x^8 - 2048  x^9)/10321920$$ Needs simplification.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: You might be interested in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213187/the-sine-cardinal-function-and-f-n-frac12-int-0-infty-frac-sinn-xxn). It turns out the polynomials I was asking about can be expressed in consistently aesthetic forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Fourier_series), one can make a general formula:
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^n k}{k^n}=-\frac{\pi^n}{2n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}B_n\left(\Big\{\frac{n-2k}{2\pi}\Big\}\right),$$
where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes fractional part of $x$. Say, continuing the examples,
$$S_{10}=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1093\pi}{672}+\frac{5883\pi^2}{896}-\frac{2449\pi^3}{288}+\frac{563\pi^4}{96}\\-\frac{1423\pi^5}{576}+\frac{43\pi^6}{64}-\frac{103\pi^7}{864}+\frac{3\pi^8}{224}-\frac{\pi^9}{1152}+\frac{\pi^{10}}{40320}.$$
BTW, $n=7$ is the first with $n>2\pi$, which causes the complication.

Comment: Ah, so that's why $n=7$ is complicated.

Comment: @metamorphy Good catch! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

**Fourier Analytic Approach**

The [Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of $\frac{\sin(x)}x$ is
$$
f(x)=\pi\!\left[-\tfrac1{2\pi}\le\xi\le\tfrac1{2\pi}\right]\tag1
$$
This would mean that the Fourier Transform of $\frac{\sin^n(x)}{x^n}$ is $f_n(\xi)=\left(\ast^n\right)\!f(\xi)$, which is the convolution of $n$ copies of $f$.

The [Poisson Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) says that
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{\sin^n(k)}{k^n}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f_n(k)\tag2
$$
The support of $f$ is $\left[-\frac1{2\pi},\frac1{2\pi}\right]$; therefore, the support of $f_n$ is $\left[-\frac{n}{2\pi},\frac{n}{2\pi}\right]$. Furthermore, since $f$ is even, $f_n$ is also. Thus,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^n(k)}{k^n}=\frac{f_n(0)-1}2+\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2\pi}\right\rfloor}f_n(k)\tag3
$$
For $n\le6$, the right side of $(3)$ is $\frac{f_n(0)-1}2$. For $7\le n\le12$, the right side of $(3)$ is $\frac{f_n(0)-1}2+f_n(1)$. For $13\le n\le18$, the right side of $(3)$ is $\frac{f_n(0)-1}2+f_n(1)+f_n(2)$. And so on.

---

**Contour Integration**

We can use contour integration to get
$$
\begin{align}
f_n(\xi)
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^n(x)}{x^n}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\infty-i}^{\infty-i}\frac{\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)^n}{(2ix)^n}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\int_{-\infty-i}^{\infty-i}\frac{e^{i(n-2k-2\pi\xi)x}}{(2ix)^n}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2-\pi\xi\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}2\pi\frac{(n-2k-2\pi\xi)^{n-1}}{2^n(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2-\pi\xi\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-2k-2\pi\xi)^{n-1}\tag4
\end{align}
$$

---

**Computation**

Applying $(4)$ to $(3)$, we can compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^n(k)}{k^n}$ for any $n$:
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
n&\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^n(k)}{k^n}\\\hline
1&\frac{\pi-1}2\\
2&\frac{\pi-1}2\\
3&\frac{3\pi-4}8\\
4&\frac{2\pi-3}6\\
5&\frac{115\pi-192}{384}\\
6&\frac{11\pi-20}{40}\\
7&\frac{5887\pi-11520}{23040}+\frac{\pi(7-2\pi)^6}{46080}\\
8&\frac{151\pi-315}{630}+\frac{\pi(4-\pi)^7}{5040}\\
9&\frac{259723\pi-573440}{1146880}+\frac{\pi(9-2\pi)^8}{10321920}-\frac{\pi(7-2\pi)^8}{1146880}\\
10&\frac{15619\pi-36288}{72576}+\frac{\pi(5-\pi)^9}{362880}-\frac{\pi(4-\pi)^9}{36288}\\
11&\frac{381773117\pi-928972800}{1857945600}+\frac{\pi(11-2\pi)^{10}}{3715891200}-\frac{11\pi(9-2\pi)^{10}}{3715891200}+\frac{11\pi(7-2\pi)^{10}}{743178240}\\
12&\frac{655177\pi-1663200}{3326400}+\frac{\pi(6-\pi)^{11}}{39916800}-\frac{\pi(5-\pi)^{11}}{3326400}+\frac{\pi(4-\pi)^{11}}{604800}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: +1. This is a very aesthetic approach!

Comment: Interesting! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

This supplements metamorphy's accepted answer which allowed me to investigate higher $n$. Define,

$$I_n=\int_0^\infty \rm{sinc}^n(k)\,dk$$

$$F_n=\frac12-I_n+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rm{sinc}^n(k)$$

We have $F_1 = F_2 = F_3 = F_4 = F_5 = F_6 = 0$. Then the simple evaluations,

$$I_7 = \frac{5887}{23040}\pi,\quad F_7 = \frac{\pi\, v^6}{6!},\quad v =\pi-\tfrac72$$

$$\;I_8 =\frac{151}{630}\pi,\quad F_8 = -\frac{\pi\, v^7}{7!},\quad v =\pi-\tfrac82$$

While the pattern for $I_n$ as a rational multiple of $\pi$ continues, the simple form of $F_n$ **does not**.

---

The next $F_n$ are *palindromic* and near-palindromic,

$$F_9 = \frac{\pi}{2^5\,8!}\,P_0$$
$$P_0 = 1+10v+28v^2+70v^3+70v^4+70v^5+28v^6+10v^7+v^8$$

where $v= 2(\pi-4)$.

$$F_{10} = \frac{\pi}{9!}\big(1+3P_1\big)$$
$$P_1 = 3+30v+120v^2+280v^3+420v^4+420v^5+280v^6+120v^7+30v^8+3v^9$$

where $v = \pi-5$.

$$F_{11} = \frac{\pi}{10!}\big(11+15P_2\big)$$
$$P_2 = \small{3+36v+168v^2+432v^3+784v^4+\frac{4536}5v^5+784v^6+432v^7+168v^8+36v^9+3v^{10}}$$

and where $v = \pi-9/2$.

**Note:** Unfortunately, higher $n$ do not seem to have similar forms. The answer given by metamorphy does not immediately imply palindromic polynomials, so one can wonder why these appear.

Comment: Related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894649/closed-form-for-integral-of-integer-powers-of-sinc-function?rq=1)