# Proving that $\int_1^\infty \big(\frac{\sin x}{x}\big)^n d x\leq e^{-n/6}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

How to prove that, for $n\geq 1$
$$\int_1^\infty \big(\frac{\sin x}{x}\big)^n d x\leq e^{-n/6}$$
I could check the case  $n=1,2$ by computation using wolfram.

I don't have any concrete proof.

Comment: Maybe helpful [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894649/closed-form-for-integral-of-integer-powers-of-sinc-function)

Comment: It can't be true. We know that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{\infty}\biggl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\biggr)^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Moreover, the Laplace's method gives $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\biggl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\biggr)^n\,\mathrm{d}x\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2/6}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{2n}}.$$ It cannot decay exponentially fast.

Comment: Sorry I have corrected

Comment: There is an exact result for the integral of $\operatorname{sinc}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}_+$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307510/a-sine-integral-int-0-infty-left-frac-sin-x-x-rightn-mathrmdx/307837#307837

Comment: @K.defaoite check again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pick a number $a \in (1, \pi)$ whose value is to be determined later. Then

$$ \int_{a}^{\infty} \left| \frac{\sin x}{x} \right|^n \, \mathrm{d}x
\leq \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^n}
= \frac{a^{1-n}}{n-1} \tag{1} $$

Next, for $0 < x < \pi$, the Weierstrass factorization for $\sin x$ gives

$$ 0 \leq \frac{\sin x}{x}
= \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right)
\leq \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/(k\pi)^2}
= e^{-x^2/6}, $$

and so, it follows that

$$ \int_{1}^{a} \left( \frac{\sin x}{x} \right)^n \, \mathrm{d}x
\leq \int_{1}^{a} e^{-nx^2/6} \, \mathrm{d}x
\leq (a - 1)e^{-n/6}. \tag{2} $$

The sum of the bounds $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ turns to be minimized at $a = e^{1/6}$, and we use this choice hereafter. Then combining $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ together,

$$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\sin x}{x} \right)^n \, \mathrm{d}x
\leq e^{-n/6} \left( \frac{n}{n-1}e^{1/6} - 1 \right) $$

We can check that $\frac{3}{2}e^{1/6} - 1 < 1$, and so, this confirms that the inequality in the question holds for $n \geq 3$. The cases $n = 1, 2$ can be checked individually.

Comment: How to do you get   that $\left( \frac{n}{n-1}e^{1/6} - 1 \right)<1$ I don't think it holds for n large.

Comment: @GuyFsone, The limit of the left-hand side is $e^{1/6}-1\approx0.18136$, which is less than one!