# Evaluation an improper integral

Tags: integration, analysis

Is it possible to use Fourier transform to evaluate the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^3dx$$

Comment: See (37) [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894649/closed-form-for-integral-of-integer-powers-of-sinc-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let
$$ f(x)=\bigg(\frac{\sin x}{x}\bigg)^2,g(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x} $$
and then
$$ \hat f(\xi)=?, \hat g(\xi)=?$$
Next use the Parsevell Identity
$$  \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(x)\bar{g(x)} dx=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\hat f(\xi) \bar{\hat g(\xi)}d\xi. $$