# Integral Using Feynman's Method

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup\renewcommand{\dd}[1]{\,\mathrm{d}#1}$I was trying to solve this integral using Feynman's Method: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ \sin^{2}(x)}{x^{2}} \dd{x}$$
I thought I'd use Feynman's Method because I was able to solve this integral using the same method: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ \sin(x)}{x} \dd{x}$$
Here are my steps:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ \sin^{2}(x)}{x^{2}}  \dd{x} \\
I(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ \sin^{2}(tx)}{x^{2}}dx ~, \qquad I(1)=I \\  \begin{aligned}
I'(t) = \frac{\dd{}}{\dd{t}} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ \sin^{2}(tx)}{x^{2}} \dd{x} &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{ \sin^{2}(tx)}{x^2} \dd{x} \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2 \sin(tx)\cos(tx)}{x}  \dd{x} \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ \sin(2tx)}{x} \dd{x} 
\end{aligned} \\
\begin{aligned}
I''(t) = \frac{\dd{}}{\dd{t}} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ \sin(2tx)}x \dd{x} &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{ \sin(2tx)}x \dd{x} \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}2 \sin(2tx) \cos(2tx) \dd{x} \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(4tx) \dd{x}  
\end{aligned} \\
u=4tx \implies \dd{u} = 4t \dd{x} \implies \frac1{4t} \dd{u} = \dd{x} \\
\begin{aligned}I''(t) &= \frac1{4t}\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(u) \dd{u} \\
&=\frac{1}{4t}\bigl[-\cos(u) \bigr]_{0}^{\infty} 
\end{aligned} $$
But $-\cos(\infty)$ is not defined, so this is where I got stuck. With whatever hint or answer you provide, it would be greatly appreciated if you explained what lead you to this solution and not just why its correct.$\endgroup$

Comment: As $I(t)=tI(1)$, I suspect you'll just go round in circles with this method.

Comment: Is there any other form of substitution that can be made? In the past, I’ve made substitutions in the arguments of the trig functions (as seen above), but I’ve also done a substitution where I put the parameter $t$ as the exponent.

Comment: You say that you know how to integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin(x)}{x}dx$ , so why don't you stop after $I'$ ?

Comment: Because at $I’(t)$, its $\frac{sin(2tx)}{x}$, and unless there’s a good u-sub for that, there’s no way to get it to be $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin(2tx)}{x}dx= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin(2tx)}{x(2t)}d(2tx)$

Comment: I’m not understanding the notation that you are using for the differential. Also, is $x$ now a function of $t$? Also, how does this help?

Comment: Treat $t$ as a fixed parameter.

Comment: So then is the denominator equivalent to $2tx$? And what does $d(2tx)$ mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93342/discussion-between-itislastthursday-and-user617446).

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$
I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(ax)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Note that $I(0)=0$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}I(a)
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{2\sin(ax)\cos(ax)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(2ax)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[3pt]
&=\frac\pi2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=I(1)\\
&=I(0)+\int_0^1\frac\pi2\,\mathrm{d}a\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice (+1)! Isn't easier to integrate by parts?:) BTW, how is it going lately?

Comment: It might be a bit simpler, but not much. However, they asked for this approach.The question I have is how they they handled $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x$ with this approach. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338582), I use Fourier series to compute this integral (avoiding contour integration).

Comment: OK, great. Have a nice day! Returning to my work.

Comment: I hope your work is going well these days!