# Complex analysis integral residuum

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-principal-value

> I am asked to evaluate, principal value of
> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{a^2-x^2} \, dx=\pi \frac{\sin (a)}{a},a>0$$

If we start from $$\oint\limits_{C}\frac{e^{iz}}{a^2-z^2}dz,a>0$$ the line $C$ is composed of the half circle $\Gamma$, pole circles at $-a,a, \gamma_1,\gamma_2$ whose circumferences are ($r,r_1,r_2$),  and a portion of the $x$-axis. If we use the Cauchy remainder theorem, we get
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{ir\cos \theta -r\sin \theta}}
                {a^2-r^2e^{2-\theta}}
                ire^{i\theta} \, d\theta
&+ \int_{-r}^{-a-r_2} f(x) \, dx
 + J_2 \\
&+ \int_{-a+r_2}^{a-r_1} f(x) \, dx
 + J_1
 + \int_{a+r_1}^r f(x) \, dx
 = 0
\end{split}
$$
Since $\left|\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{ir\cos \theta -rsin \theta}}{a^2-r^2 e^{2-\theta}}ire^{i\theta} \, d\theta\right|\leq{\frac{\pi r}{r^2-a^2},(r>a)}$
We get $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{ir\cos \theta -r\sin \theta}}{a^2-r^2e^{2-\theta}}ire^{i\theta} \, d\theta=0$$
Evaluating residuum at $J_{1}$ and $J_{2}$ we get $$J_1=\operatorname{Res}f(a)=\lim_{x \to a}(a-x)\frac{e^{ix}}{(a-x)(a+x)} =\frac{e^{ia}}{2a}$$ and $$J_2= \operatorname{Res}f(-a)=\lim_{x \to -a}(a+x)\frac{e^{ix}}{(a-x)(a+x)}=\frac{e^{-ia}}{2a}$$ In my book the author got $J_{1}=\frac{\pi i}{2a}e^{ia}\land J_2=-\frac{\pi i}{2a} e^{-ia}$ Where does the $\pi i$ come from ? also, why - in the second one? Is it because the residuum is at $-a$?  Then, adding those two gives us the result, but still, where does $\pi$ come from?

Comment: Im just confused where does the $\pi i $ come from, also the - in the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the author meant to write $\pi i$ times the residue terms.  And the residue at $z=a$ is given by

$$\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)\frac{e^{iz}}{a^2-z^2}=-\frac{e^{ia}}{2a}$$

---

So, in order to provide support of your analysis, let's start from scratch and evaluate the closed contour integral

$$\begin{align}
0&=\oint_C\frac{e^{iz}}{a^2-z^2}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_{-R}^{-a-r}\frac{e^{ix}}{a^2-x^2}\,dx+\int_\pi^0 \frac{e^{i(-a+re^{i\phi})}}{a^2-(-a+re^{i\phi})^2}\,ire^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_{-a+r}^{a-r}\frac{e^{ix}}{a^2-x^2}\,dx+\int_\pi^0 \frac{e^{i(a+re^{i\phi})}}{a^2-(a+re^{i\phi})^2}\,ire^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_{a+r}^R \frac{e^{ix}}{a^2-x^2}\,dx+\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{iRe^{i\phi}}}{a^2-(Re^{i\phi})^2}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\tag1
\end{align}$$

The last integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ vanishes as $R\to\infty$.   And as $r\to 0^+$, the second and fourth integrals on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approach $-\frac{i\pi e^{-ia}}{2a}$ and $\frac{i\pi e^{ia}}{2a}$, respectively.

We find, therefore, that the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral of interest is

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{a^2-x^2}\,dx\right)&=\lim_{r\to 0^+}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-a-r}\frac{\sin(x)}{a^2-x^2}\,dx+\int_{-a+r}^{a-r}\frac{\sin(x)}{a^2-x^2}\,dx\\\\
+\int_{a+r}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{a^2-x^2}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi\sin(a)}{a}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown.

Comment: Sure.  There is a factor of $i$ inside the second and fourth integrals of $(1)$.  The integration extends from $\phi=\pi$ to $\phi=0$.  Does that help?

Comment: Let me ask something, the values of the integrals, 2 and 4 are the residuums of their functions? Can you evaluate them with great detail? Sorry if im asking a dumb question, im still a bit confused....Even tho i got the right answer...Let me ask again, i evaluate 2 and 4 like this, $$\lim_{z \to a}(z-a)\frac{e^{iz}}{(a-z)(a+z)}=-\frac{e^{ia}}{2a}$$ and i multiply them both with $\pi i$ because the range is  $\pi$ and they boith have $i$ in their integral forms?

Comment: I'll evaluate the second one.  Note that we have  $$\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\int_\pi^0 \frac{e^{i(-a+re^{i\phi})}}{a^2-(-a+re^{i\phi})^2}\,ire^{i\phi}\,d\phi&=-ie^{-ia}\lim_{r\to 0^+}\int_0^\pi \frac{re^{i\phi}e^{ire^{i\phi}}}{re^{i\phi}(2a-re^{i\phi})}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-ie^{-ia}\lim_{r\to 0^+}\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{ire^{i\phi}}}{2a-re^{i\phi}}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-ie^{-ia}\int_0^\pi \frac1{2a}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-\frac{i\pi e^{-ia}}{2a}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much for your help ! I solved the other one and got it all right!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\large\mbox{An}\ alternative:}$

---

With $\ds{\Lambda > \verts{a}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\mrm{P.V.}
\int_{-\Lambda}^{\Lambda}{\cos\pars{x} \over
a^{2} - x^{2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2\verts{a}}\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\Lambda}^{\Lambda}{\cos\pars{x} \over
x + \verts{a}}\,\dd x -
{1 \over 2\verts{a}}\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\Lambda}^{\Lambda}{\cos\pars{x} \over
x - \verts{a}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2\verts{a}}\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\Lambda + \verts{a}}^{\Lambda + \verts{a}}
{\cos\pars{x - \verts{a}} \over
x}\,\dd x + \pars{~\verts{a} \mapsto -\verts{a}~}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2\verts{a}}\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\Lambda + \verts{a}}^{\Lambda - \verts{a}}
{\cos\pars{x - \verts{a}} \over
x}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] + &\
{1 \over 2\verts{a}}
\int_{\Lambda - \verts{a}}^{\Lambda + \verts{a}}
{\cos\pars{x - \verts{a}} \over
x}\,\dd x+ \pars{~\verts{a} \mapsto -\verts{a}~}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2\verts{a}}\int_{0}^{\Lambda - \verts{a}}
{\cos\pars{x - \verts{a}} - \cos\pars{-x - \verts{a}} \over
x}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] + &\
{1 \over 2\verts{a}}
\int_{\Lambda - \verts{a}}^{\Lambda + \verts{a}}
{\cos\pars{x - \verts{a}} \over
x}\,\dd x+ \pars{~\verts{a} \mapsto -\verts{a}~}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\sin\pars{\verts{a}} \over \verts{a}}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\Lambda - \verts{a}}
{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\to \color{red}{\large{\pi \over 2}}\ \mrm{as}\ \Lambda\ \to \infty}}
\\[2mm] + &\
{1 \over 2\verts{a}}\
\underbrace{\int_{\Lambda - \verts{a}}^{\Lambda + \verts{a}}
{\cos\pars{x - \verts{a}} \over
x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\color{red}{\Large\S :}\ \to \color{red}{\large 0}\ \mrm{as}\ \Lambda\ \to \infty}} + \pars{~\verts{a} \mapsto -\verts{a}~}
\end{align}

---

Then, as $\ds{\Lambda \to \infty}$,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\mrm{P.V.}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{x} \over
a^{2} - x^{2}}\,\dd x} =
{\pi\sin\pars{\verts{a}} \over 2\verts{a}} +
{\pi\sin\pars{-\verts{a}} \over 2\pars{-\verts{a}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\pi\,{\sin\pars{a} \over a}} \\ &
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\color{red}{\Large\S :}}$
Note that
\begin{align}
0 & < \verts{\int_{\Lambda - \verts{a}}^{\Lambda + \verts{a}}
{\cos\pars{x - \verts{a}} \over
x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & < 
\int_{\Lambda - \verts{a}}^{\Lambda + \verts{a}}
{\dd x \over x} =
\ln\pars{\Lambda + \verts{a} \over \Lambda - \verts{a}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \Lambda\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,
\color{red}{\Large 0}
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) I like this one my friend.

Comment: Thanks, Mark.${}$

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks, Mark.

Comment: Of course; my pleasure Felix.

Answer (score 0):

The Cauchy Principal Value
$$
\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{a^2-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
is the integral along a path that looks like this

[image]

where the gaps on each side of the points are the same, infinitesimal, size.

To compute the integral along the disjoint contours above, we connect those contours with counter-clockwise semi-circles around the two singularities, which adds $\pi i$ times the sum of the residues at those singularities:

[image]

Note that
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=a}\left(\frac{\cos(z)}{a^2-z^2}\right)
&=\operatorname*{Res}_{z=a}\frac1{2a}\left(\frac{\cos(z)}{a-z}+\cancel{\frac{\cos(z)}{a+z}}\right)\\
&=-\frac{\cos(a)}{2a}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-a}\left(\frac{\cos(z)}{a^2-z^2}\right)
&=\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-a}\frac1{2a}\left(\cancel{\frac{\cos(z)}{a-z}}+\frac{\cos(z)}{a+z}\right)\\
&=\frac{\cos(a)}{2a}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the sum of the residues at the singularities is $0$.

We now write $\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2$ and close the contour with two huge semi-circles:

[image]

$\gamma^-$ consists of the bumpy contour along the real axis and lower (green) semi-circle.
$$
\frac12\oint_{\gamma^-}\frac{e^{-iz}}{a^2-z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z=0
$$
since there are no singularities inside $\gamma^-$.

$\gamma^+$ consists of the bumpy contour along the real axis and upper (red) semi-circle.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\oint_{\gamma^+}\frac{e^{iz}}{a^2-z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\frac12\oint_{\gamma^+}\frac{e^{iz}}{2a}\left(\frac1{a-z}+\frac1{a+z}\right)\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac{2\pi i}{4a}\left(-e^{ia}+e^{-ia}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi{a}\sin(a)
\end{align}
$$
Since the integrals along the semi-circular contours vanish as radius of the circle goes to $\infty$, we get that the integral along the bumpy, real-axis contour is
$$
\int_\text{bumpy}\frac{\cos(z)}{a^2-z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z=\frac\pi{a}\sin(a)
$$

The integral along the bumpy, real-axis contour is the principal value integral plus $\pi i$ times the sum of the residues at the singularities, which was $0$. Therefore, we get that
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{a^2-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac\pi{a}\sin(a)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Real Approach**
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{a^2-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{2a}\left(\frac1{a-x}+\frac1{a+x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{a}\frac1{a+x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)\cos(a)+\sin(x)\sin(a)}{a}\frac1{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\[9pt]
&=\frac{\cos(a)}a\,\underbrace{\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x}_0+\frac{\sin(a)}a\,\underbrace{\mathrm{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x}_\pi\tag4\\
&=\pi\frac{\sin(a)}a\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: partial fractions
$(2)$: distribute then substitute $x\mapsto-x$ in the left sum
$(3)$: substitute $x\mapsto x-a$
$(4)$: distribute
$(5)$: integral of an odd function is $0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi$

---

**Integral of Sinc**

This can be tackled in a couple of real analytic ways. One is using equation $(9)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338582). Another is
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\color{#C00}{\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}}\int_0^\pi\sin(x)\color{#C00}{\frac{(-1)^k}{x+k\pi}}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag6\\
&=\int_0^\pi\sin(x)\color{#C00}{\csc(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag7\\[9pt]
&=\pi\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(6)$: use $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin(x)$
$(7)$: apply equation $(8)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3819077)
$(8)$: integrate