# Integrating the Difference between Sine and its Maclaurin Series

Tags: definite-integrals, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals

The integral in question:

Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer.

$$
\int_0^\infty 
\frac{1}{x^{2n+3}} 
\left ( 
\sin x - 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{(2k + 1)!}
\right )
\mathrm{d}x
$$

I was given this problem to try for fun from a professor about two months ago and haven't made a dent in it.
If possible, I'd like someone to show how they get to their answer, but please keep in mind that I haven't learned contour integration or complex analysis, but know of a few tricks like Feynman's.

What I've tried:

Writing out the terms to integrate by segments, using the Cosine Maclaurin series and substituting (pi/2 -x) to get the Sine series in a different way, integration by parts (2n+3) times or such to simplify, and a lot more I'm probably forgetting.

I know this site is full of integral-calculating gods, so if this piques your interest please have an attempt and share below.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. In the future you should write out the integrals and equations in latex, rather than embedding a picture. It's a little bit more work upfront, but it makes it easier to search for similar problems if anyone else has this question down the road! I've edited this one, so this is mainly a for-future-reference comment

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I was going to repost the question with the latex equation, but MSE said I needed 10 rep before I could do that. I really appreciate you doing that for me!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via Integration by Parts.
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^{2n+3}}\left(\sin(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{-1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^{2n+1}}\left(\sin(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\int_0^\infty\frac1x\,\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\[3pt]
&=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\frac\pi2\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: integrate by parts twice
$(2)$: repeat $(1)$ $n$ more times
$(3)$: see $(9)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338582)

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that you enjoy hypergeometric functions
$$I_n=\int_0^\infty 
\frac{1}{x^{2n+3}} 
\left ( 
\sin x - 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{(2k + 1)!}
\right )
\,dx$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{(2k + 1)!}=\frac{(-1)^n x^{2 n+3} \,
   _1F_2\left(1;n+2,n+\frac{5}{2};-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)}{(2 n+3)!}+\sin (x)$$

$$I_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\Gamma (2 n+4)}\int_0^\infty \, _1F_2\left(1;n+2,n+\frac{5}{2};-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\,dx$$
$$I_n=(-1)^{n+1}\,\frac{   \pi}{2\,\Gamma (2 n+3)}$$