# Eigenfunction of the $n$-torus

Tags: fourier-series

Let $\phi$ be an eigenfunction of the Laplacian $\Delta$ on the $n$-torus $T^n$, with eigenvalue $-\lambda$, i.e. $\Delta \phi + \lambda \phi =0$, then :

$$ \phi (x)= \sum_{|n^2|=\lambda} \hat{\phi} (n) e^{in \cdot x}.$$

Why can we write $\phi$ this way?

Comment: Wierdly enough, I posted a related question an hour ago. I believe the link in the beginning of my question might help you.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add the link. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341066/fourier-series-on-a-2-torus) it is. Hope it helps.