# Riemannian generalization/adaption of the Hubbard–Stratonovich transformation

Tags: riemannian-geometry, integral-transforms, heat-equation

I'd like to write the [Hubbard–Stratonovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard%E2%80%93Stratonovich_transformation) (HS) transformation of  a scalar function on a Riemannian manifold (curved space). This transformation is quite simple in Euclidean space. One can consider it as a [Fourier transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of a Guassian function:
$$
\exp\left(-\frac{a}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)  f(x)~=~\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2\pi a}}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2a}\right)   f(x+y), \qquad a~>~0.
$$ 
However, my question is can one apply HS transformation to a scalar function on the compact Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$? If so, how?

I couldn't understand how to define the Fourier transform on a compact Riemannian manifold. It seems to me the Fourier transform is defined by the [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality).. I've found that a question about the Fourier transform has been asked at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13902/does-a-fourier-transformation-on-a-pseudo-riemannian-manifold-make-sense).. The answer given is actually nice but it goes little technical and I'm not familiar with that.. Nevertheless, I guess one can write the Hubbard-Stratonovich transform:
$$
\exp\left(-\frac{a}{2}\Delta\right)  f({x})~=~ (2\pi a)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\int d^n{y}\sqrt {g(y)}\exp\left(-\frac{{y}^2}{2a}\right) f({x+y})~,
$$
where $\Delta$ is the [Laplace–Beltrami operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator). In addition, I read that the [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform#Generalizations) can be defined on any Riemannian manifold, but it doesn't make sense to me, I couldn't find any proper references and don't know how to write this transform.

Context:

My real problem involves the free energy of a harmonic oscillator on a Riemannian manifold which leads to an trasformation similar to the HS transformation. Indeed, potential energy of harmonic oscillator is $U=\frac{1}{2}kd(y,y_0)^2$ which $k$ is a constant, $d(y,y_0)$ is distance. I simply assumed that $d(y, .)^2=y^2$. Under what conditions on the Riemannian manifold $M$ can I write a transformation similar to to the one mentioned above? As far as I understand, one can define the FT on a Riemannian manifold when it is either a Lie group or a symmetric space.

PS: I have originally posted this question at [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205399/riemannian-generalization-adaption-of-the-hubbard-stratonovich-transformation) but perhaps math.SE is a better place for this kind of integral-transforms.

I would appreciate answers not demanding an all profound background...